# Отображение изображения на месте клика пользователем

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Пишу браузерную игру, в которой при клике на определенное место должна отображаться картинка. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

как пример:

```js
$(document).click(function (e) {
    $('<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/360/emoticons/128/ok.png" />').css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY,
        position: 'absolute'
    }).appendTo($('body'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можешь использовать jQuery и его обработчик [событий при нажатии](https://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-clicks)
Получая координату x и у можешь использовать абсолютное позиционирование для вывода картинки